# Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, show that there exist isometric isomorphism between $L(X,Y)$ and $L(X^*,Y^*)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $X^*$,$Y^*$ be their dual spaces. $L(X,Y)$ denote the space of continuous linear functions from $X \to Y$. For each $T:X\to Y$, define $$T':Y^*\to X^*$$ such that $$l(Tx)=(T'l)(x)$$
>   For all $l \in Y^*$ and $x \in X$

Then we can show that $T'$ is a continuous linear function in $L(Y^*,X^*)$, and call it the Banach dual of $T$. Also, the map $T \to T'$ is an isometry.
However, in Michael Reed's functional analysis page $187$, it said that the map $T \to T'$ is an isometric isomorphism. I can not see why the map $T \to T'$ is surjective.

Comment: I recently asked the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495743/is-every-operator-adjoint-for-something

Comment: It really helps , thank you .